# How to configure Fair Scheduler pools with Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to execute different Spark Streaming jobs using different [Fair Scheduler pools](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools). I am playing with the `NetworkWordCount` example from the Spark GitHub repository. I modified it to run 3 pools with weights of respectively 1, 5, 10.

I knew that with Spark Streaming it is necessary to use this [workaround](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201407.mbox/%3CCAMwrk0kd9michJjqFfXZkEG_jonGOWgGC2ihYU1fiwOO+z+NoA@mail.gmail.com%3E) to assign a job to a specific pool so I modified the code in this way:

```
   wordCounts.foreachRDD(rdd =>
      rdd.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", poolName)
    )
    wordCounts.foreachRDD(rdd =>
      println(rdd.sparkContext.getLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool"))
    )
    wordCounts.print()
```

from the print in the second `foreachRDD` I can see that all the pools are working but they are not respecting the priority assigned to them. Each pool has his own data source and all of them operate at the same rate of words/s. Since the workloads are the same I assume that the problem is somewhere else but I can not see where it is.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you need to `map` before `print` to assign the pool (using the local property), i.e.

wordCounts.map(rdd => rdd.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", poolName)).print()

You could also use `ssc.sparkContext` to set the pool.